# Designing HBase Table(Schema) for location based entries

Tags: hbase

Need some points or advise for designing HBase Table(Schema) for location-based entries, i.e. Fetching Data as per

```
1. Continent
2. Country
3. States 
4. Cities
5. Pincode/Zipcode
```

Comment: @MathsRkBala stop using `inline code` and **`inline bold code`** for random terms. That's markup abuse.

Comment: @CodeCaster Okay.. But I done readability & easily identify the issue and expected results...

Comment: describe entity example too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hbase is schema less database, it can expand vertically with many columns. So we design Hbase schema generally with following aspects

### Columns Family

To segregate columns by its feature. Generally should not be more than 3 column family for better performance.

### Data Access Pattern

It depends your usage of Hbase. I mean how you would like to query Hbase, this helps you to Design Hbase key. You have to make sure that RowKey should be idempotent. Strong Design of RowKey is must in Hbase. It’s helps you to avoid full table scan. Keeping Fixed length RowKey format helps you to improve performance.

### Distribution of Data over cluster

After Designing RowKey, you have to focus on row key salting to avoid HotSpot issue in Hbase.

If you your Data Access patten is

1. Continent
2. Country
3. States
4. Cities
5. Pincode/Zipcode

Then your key should look like

```
SaltingKey-Continent-Country-States-Cities-Pincode
```

For Example:

```
//x001-ASIA######-SINGAPORE#-CHANGI####-VILLAGE###-477000
```

I hope this help to get started.

[guidelines-hbase-schema-design](https://mapr.com/blog/guidelines-hbase-schema-design/)